# Number-guessing game based on Rust tutorial

Tags: beginner, rust, number-guessing-game

This is how I implemented the guessing game - [chapter 2 of the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html).

```rust
use std::io;
use std::io::Error;
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::num::ParseIntError;

use rand::Rng;


enum MyReadLineError {
    FailReadLine(Error)
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum MyReadU32Line {
    FailReadLine(Error),
    FailParse(ParseIntError)
}


fn my_read_line() -> Result<String, MyReadLineError> {
    let mut input = String::new();
    let result = io::stdin().read_line(&mut input);
    match result {
        Ok(_) => Ok(input),
        Err(error ) => Err(MyReadLineError::FailReadLine(error)),
    }
}

fn my_read_u32_line() -> Result<u32, MyReadU32Line> {
    match my_read_line() {
        Result::Ok(line) =>
            match line.trim().parse::<u32>() {
                Ok(value) => Ok(value),
                Err(error) => Err(MyReadU32Line::FailParse(error)),
            }

        Result::Err(MyReadLineError::FailReadLine(error)) => Err(MyReadU32Line::FailReadLine(error)),
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Guess the number!");

    let secret_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 101);

    loop {
        println!("Please input your guess.");
        let guess = my_read_u32_line();
        match guess {
            Ok (value) => match value.cmp(&secret_number) {
                Ordering::Less => println!("Too small!"),
                Ordering::Greater => println!("Too big!"),
                Ordering::Equal => {
                    println!("You win!");
                    break;
                },
            }
            Err (_) => println!("Sorry I couldn't read a u32 from your input! Please try again."),
        }
    }
}
```

This works as expected but I would like to flatten the matches so that doesn't look at verbose, is that possible. Also is there any other way to make that code look better, more readable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Welcome to Rust!

## Code Formatting

There are some inconsistencies in your formatting — I have run
`cargo fmt` to get rid of them.

## Naming

There's no need to prefix everything with `My` or `my_` — in
Rust, your names won't as easily clash with existing names as might be
the case in certain other languages.

## Error handling

For applications, I suggest using the [`anyhow`](https://docs.rs/anyhow) crate to manage
errors — it reduces much of the boilerplate.  Just add

```
anyhow = "1.0"
```

to the `[dependencies]` section of your `Cargo.toml`.

## Helper functions

The `my_read_line` function can be simplified with the `?` operator:

```
use anyhow::Result;

fn read_line() -> Result<String> {
    let mut input = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut input)?;
    Ok(input)
}
```

`my_read_u32_line` can be similarly simplified:

```
fn read_u32() -> Result<u32> {
    Ok(read_line()?.trim().parse()?)
}
```

## Magic numbers

We can define constants for the range of the number:

```
const MIN: u32 = 1;
const MAX: u32 = 100;

// later
let secret_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(MIN, MAX + 1);
```

## Organization

I might reorganize the `main` function to reduce indentation:

```
loop {
    println!("Please input your guess.");

    let guess = match read_u32() {
        Ok(guess) => guess,
        Err(_) => {
            println!(
                "Sorry I couldn't read a u32 from your input! \
                Please try again."
            );
            continue;
        }
    };

    match guess.cmp(&secret_number) {
        Ordering::Less => println!("Too small!"),
        Ordering::Greater => println!("Too big!"),
        Ordering::Equal => {
            println!("You win!");
            break;
        }
    };
}
```

## Final result

```
use anyhow::Result;
use rand::Rng;
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::io;

const MIN: u32 = 1;
const MAX: u32 = 100;

fn read_line() -> Result<String> {
    let mut input = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut input)?;
    Ok(input)
}

fn read_u32() -> Result<u32> {
    Ok(read_line()?.trim().parse()?)
}

fn main() {
    println!("Guess the number!");

    let secret_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(MIN, MAX + 1);

    loop {
        println!("Please input your guess.");

        let guess = match read_u32() {
            Ok(guess) => guess,
            Err(_) => {
                println!(
                    "Sorry I couldn't read a u32 from your input! \
                    Please try again."
                );
                continue;
            }
        };

        match guess.cmp(&secret_number) {
            Ordering::Less => println!("Too small!"),
            Ordering::Greater => println!("Too big!"),
            Ordering::Equal => {
                println!("You win!");
                break;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is really awesome!!! Real nice of you =]